# NoSuchMethodError while using map in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mapping, nosuchmethoderror

Please Help..an error occurred while running the app on emulator....NoSuchMethodError[Screen Shot of my code and Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCzGG.jpg)

Comment: You `questions[_questionIndex]['answers']` is null. Use a `collection if` to avoid it.

Comment: Where to use it. Please explain

Comment: I have added an answer, check it out.

Comment: I have added an answer, check it out if that's clear. If not tell me which part confuses you.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `questions[_questionIndex]['answers']` is coming to be `null`, you can't call the `map` function on it. That is why the error is coming.

So, before you try to access it with `map`, check if the `List` actually exists or not.

You can do this in your case using a collection if,

```
children: [
  Question(questions[_questionIndex]['questionText']),
  if (questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] != null)
    ...(questions[_questionIndex]['answers'] as List<String>)
      .map((answer) => Answer(_answerQuestion, answer)).toList(),
],
```